# GroupBox.Header not working

Tags: c#, wpf, header, groupbox

I am trying to add an image to my GroupBox Header like so:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Test Box" />
            <Image Source="MyImage.jpg" />                   
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox.Header>
    .....
    <!-- All my other code which I know works correctly -->
    .....
<GroupBox>
```

However, what shows up for my `GroupBox` `Header` is:

[image]

I see this method of modifying the `GroupBox` `Header` all over the web when I search on how to do this but I cannot get it to work.  I even tried removing the `Image` in case that was causing an issue and it still give the same result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it looks as if, in your custom template, you use `TextBlock` instead of `ContentPresenter` to display header content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Ganesh's post, I did a search for a GroupBox style and found that there was one in my project that I was unaware of.  The GroupBox style was defined as follows:

```
<!-- GroupBox & GroupBox.Header Style -->
<Style x:Key="GroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />

    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource GroupBoxStyle}" />
```

By changing my code to the following I was able to override the default GroupBox style:

```
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Julius Caesar"/>
                    <Image Source="MyImage.jpg" /> 
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
        ......
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Try HeaderTemplate. Refer below code.

```
<GroupBox>
            <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Test Box" />
                        <Image Source="MyImage.jpg" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>                    
            </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupBox>
```

Comment: Brian shouldn't need to do this, what he is trying should work.

Comment: @Steven.. Agreed.But I feel but this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: I have been using headerTemplates all the time and they work fine, but looks Header should work as well

Comment: I selected this as the best answer as my issue turned out to be a GroupBox Style that I didn't know existed in the project.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new WPF project using the default Visual Studio template, then inserted this in the XAML as the content of the `Grid` element:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Test Box" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Width="50" Height="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

It's using a `Rectangle` instead of an image, but it worked fine for me.

The only thing I can think of is that something has changed the default `GroupBox` template. Maybe try the XAML above in a new project and see if you can get that to work?

Which version of Windows are you using? I know the default templates differ slightly between Windows versions. The above was tested on Windows 7.